# Change font typeface of ProgressDialog within DialogFragment

Tags: android

May I know is it possible to change the font typeface of `ProgressDialog`'s message display, within `DialogFragment`?

```
public class LoadFromCloudTaskFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.getActivity());
        this.progressDialog.setMessage(progressMessage);
        this.progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        return progressDialog;
    }
```

Create a custom class by inheriting from `ProgressDialog` might be one of the ways. However, I wish to know is there any better alternative? Sadly, we do not have `ProgressDialog.Builder`.

One of the alternative I had tried is

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.getActivity());
    this.progressDialog.setMessage(progressMessage);
    this.progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    Utils.setCustomFont(this.progressDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message), Utils.ROBOTO_LIGHT_FONT);

    return progressDialog;
}
```

But this will give me error

> android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called
>   before adding content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**One of the suggested solution is as follow. But I don't think this is a good way. Any further suggestion are very much welcomed.**

```
public class ProgressDialogEx extends ProgressDialog {
    public ProgressDialogEx(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View view = this.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        if (view != null) {
            // Shouldn't be null. Just to be paranoid enough.
            Utils.setCustomTypeface(view, Utils.ROBOTO_LIGHT_FONT);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class LoadFromCloudTaskFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialogEx(this.getActivity());
        this.progressDialog.setMessage(progressMessage);
        this.progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        return progressDialog;
    }
```

### Utils.setCustomTypeface

```
public static final Typeface ROBOTO_LIGHT_TYPE_FACE = Typeface.createFromAsset(MyApplication.instance().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");

public static void setCustomTypeface(View view, Typeface typeFace) {
    if (view instanceof TextView) {
        ((TextView)view).setTypeface(typeFace);
    } else if (view instanceof EditText) {
        ((EditText)view).setTypeface(typeFace);
    } else if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)view;
        int count = viewGroup.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            setCustomTypeface(viewGroup.getChildAt(i), typeFace);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is Utils activity?

Comment: please discribe Utils

Answer (score 4):

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
SpannableStringBuilder spannableSB = new SpannableStringBuilder(getString(R.string.text_please_wait));
spannableSB.setSpan (new CustomTypefaceSpan("fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf", font), 0, spannableSB.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
loadDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, null, spannableSB, true, false);
```

---

```
public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends TypefaceSpan {

    private final Typeface newType;

    public CustomTypefaceSpan(String family, Typeface type) {
       super(getContext(),family);
       newType = type;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
         applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType);
    }

    private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
        int oldStyle;
        Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
        if (old == null) {
            oldStyle = 0;
        } else {
            oldStyle = old.getStyle();
        }

        int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
        if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
            paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        }

        if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
            paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
        }

        paint.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is perfectly working for me. and i made same changes

Answer (score 3):

As seen from documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    static MyDialogFragment newInstance() {
        return new MyDialogFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world, container, false);
        View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        ((TextView)tv).setText("This is an instance of MyDialogFragment");
        return v;
    }
}
```

I'd suspect you can to provide custom layout XML for the DialogFragment.

After I'd proceed with setting typeface with this utility class:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Taken from bug on b.android.com
 * https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904
 * <p>
 * Optimizes way to work with typefaces and avoids context related memory leak
 * */
public class Typefaces {

    private static final Map<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

    public static Typeface get(Context c, String name) {
        synchronized (cache) {
            if (!cache.containsKey(name)) {
                Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),
                        String.format("fonts/%s.ttf", name));
                cache.put(name, t);
            }
            return cache.get(name);
        }
    }

    public static Typeface _default(Context c) {
        return get(c, "verdana");
    }

    public static void setFonts(Context c, TextView... tvs) {
        for (TextView t : tvs) {
            if (t != null)
                t.setTypeface(_default(c));
        }
    }

}
```

Which assumes you have custom font placed in `assets/fonts/verdana.ttf` (if using `_default()` method)

Comment: I rather not to provide own view. I prefer to use back the default ProgressDialog, by just changing its font typeface. If not, I rather create a custom ProgressDialog class by overriding it.

Comment: @YanChengCHEOK It's a problem, as different ROMs and versions of Android could have different layouts and different TextView id. You'd need to use reflection API to find all TextView instances in already inflated layout and set the fonts. In my opinion using custom layout is simplest way.

Answer (score 2):

While this is an old question, I have pieced together some info that may help future visitors.

Before I begin, this is not an-on-the-fly setup. It can only be done on ProgressDialog initialization and it only works with built-in fonts. Now that it was said, let's get down to business! First, we need to create a style with the parent of `android:Theme.Holo.Dialog`, as shown below, in your `styles.xml` file.

```
<style name="CustomFontDialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>
```

Then add a little piece to your initialization:

```
ProgressDialog prog = new ProgressDialog(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.CustomFontDialog)));
```

To make this answer come as close as possible to be an answer to the question though, I'm looking into a library called [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/) and it appears, by [the response to the issue](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/issues/164), that the dev plans on adding the functionality to Dialogs. Calligraphy may eventually be what you want to use, but for now you'll have to use a custom View hack for non-system fonts. Anyway, I hope this helps some visitor that was searching for this answer as I was.