# custom font in progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar

I would like to use custom font in progressbar message as "Loading" and "Sync Data, Please wait..." to change custom font.Here is my code. How can I get settypeface method to change custom font.

```
 private void createProgressBar() {
    if (progressDialog == null) {
        String msg = "";String title= "";
        if (common.LanguageInfo.equals("LOCAL")) {
            msg = "အလုပ္လုပ္ေနပါသည္";title="တင္ေန...";
        }else {
            msg= "Sync Data, please wait ...";
            title = "Loading...";
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                     "fonts/" + FontInfo.default_font); 
        } 

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

        progressDialog.setTitle(title);


        progressDialog.setMessage(msg);

        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);

        progressDialog.setMax(100);

        progressDialog.setProgress(0);

        progressDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164280/change-font-typeface-of-progressdialog-within-dialogfragment

Comment: create custom `ProgressDialog`

Comment: @DarshilShah http://danielme.com/tip-android-28-progressdialog-personalizado/ Give your feedback